# String Parameter in jquery ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The Curl of the API says that this is the correct format:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "2018062703,2018062703" "http://XX.XX.XX/api/my_url"
```

This API need parameters like this:

[image]

I'm trying to send them with this code:

```
var data = "2018062703,2018062703";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    url: 'my/api/url',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: etc...
```

But I get a 404 not found. In the console of Chrome I got this:

What I'm doing wrong? In the web of the API when I put the parameters as a string "2018062703,2018062703" it works.

[image]

Comment: -d "2018062703,2018062703" is not JSON.....

Comment: You get a 404 and it is saying your data is wrong? wouldn't it be a 5XX ?

Comment: Yes, I know it's weird, but with the same URL of the API by Swagger works ok.

Comment: Look at the answer below and look at your swagger documentation.  The parameter key is "filtro".

Comment: your data type is `json` in ajax call and you are passing string. convert it to json and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` parameter in your AJAX call is invalid. It should look like this:

```
data: { filtro: data }
```

As it is now, you're trying to call your API with a parameter named 
`2018062703,2018062703` which has no value.

Comment: Now I have it in that way, but in Chrome console I got in `Headers -> Form Data: filtro: 2018062703,2018062703` but still 404 not found. If I change to GET (only to force to have method error) I got ` GET h ttp : //XX.XX.XX/my_api/?filtro=2018062703%2C2018062703 405 (Method Not Allowed)` which is correct

Comment: A 404 most likely means the URL you're calling is wrong. If you're 100% sure the URL is correct, it might be a bit overkill but I would record the call from Swagger and the call you're making in AJAX with a tool like Fiddler and compare them. That way, you'll see exactly what's happening.

Comment: I tried with GET method in the ajax, if the URL wasn't correct I would get a 404 too, but instead I get the 405 Method Not Allowed wich is fine.

Comment: Finally I had to JSON.stringify() my data, plus, add the contentType: "application/json",``

Comment: I will pick you answer as the correct one because it leads me to rewrite my code.

Comment: Glad I could help a bit.